# Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions

Tags: ros, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I ran

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

there have

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
```

And then I found RViz can't add RobotModel.

SOS!
Thanks All!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225050/package-%22ompl%22-does-not-follow-the-version-conventions./) by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is actually two questions in one as the issue with the RobotModel in RViz is not related at all with the OMPL warning. Please open a different question for this issue.

In any case, it is safe to ignore the OMPL warning. Current OMPL version ROS release is 1.0.0 so if you update your packages this warning should disappear. Before, it was 0.15 or something like that, thus the warning appeared, but it is of no importance.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-01-26**:
I got it,thanks.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-27**:
Please accept the answer if you consider your question was solved. Thanks.

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-01-28**:
zzzzZ,好的，不好意思。

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-02-08**:
Actually, with OMPL 1.0.0 the warning is still there. I guess the reason is that the version is 1.0.0003094, therefore is still containing leading zeros in the patch number.